# Foreign key issue - phonegap

Tags: database-design, cordova, foreign-keys, relational-database

Now I am working in a phoneGap project, in page1.html i have the following code to save some datafields from page1.html to localDB,

```
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableOne (value1 INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, value2 INTEGER,value3 TEXT)');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO ICTtableOne (value1 ,value2,value3)VALUES (?,?,?)',[value1,value2,value3]);
```

In page2.html i have th following code to save the datafields from page2.html

```
tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tableTwo (id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name  TEXT,Details TEXT,foreign_val int,FOREIGN KEY(foreign_val) REFERENCES tableOne(value1))');
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO ICTtableTwo (value1 ,value2,value3)VALUES (?,?,?)',
        [value1,value12,value13]);
```

Value1 of 'tableOne' is foreign key in 'tableTwo', but it is not showing in 'tableTwo' after each insertion is occurred, it shows blank space since other values in tableTwo are ok...
I am a starter ,so I need your valuable help...
Thanks..

> **edit:**
>   How can I get primary key value of tableOne in my foreign_val column of tableTwo..

Comment: You have to put the foreign key there yourself as a part of the ICTableTwo insert.  (I hope that ICTableOne in the second insert execute is a typo.)

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: thanks!! sorry.., i had a misconcept that foreign key column in the tableTwo would automatically filled out from tableOne since tableTwo is referencing to it..